# Text file saved. When opened in Notepad, lines are indented. Unsure of why that is?

Tags: output, text-files, notepad

Code: 
    private void HomeSavebtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

```
        Stream myStream;
        SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog();
        saveFileDialog1.Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*";
        saveFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 2;
        saveFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = true;

        if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            string line = string.Format("{0} {1} {2} {3} {4} {5} {6} {7} {8} {9} {10} {11} {12} {13} {14} {15} {16} {17} {18} {19} {20}" +
                "{21} {22} {23} {24} {25} {26} {27} {28} {29} {30} {31} {32} {33} {34} {35} {36} {37} {38} {39}"
            , txtFirstNamedInsured.Text + Environment.NewLine // {0}
            , comboOccupation.Text + Environment.NewLine //      {1}
            , comboEducation.Text + Environment.NewLine //       {2}
            , txtBirthDate.Text + Environment.NewLine //         {3}
            , txtSocial.Text + Environment.NewLine //            {4}
            , comboGender.Text + Environment.NewLine //          {5}
            , txtLicense.Text + Environment.NewLine //           {6}
            , comboMaritalStatus.Text + Environment.NewLine //   {7}
            , txtAddress.Text + Environment.NewLine //           {8}
            , txtNewAddress.Text + Environment.NewLine //        {9}
            , txtSecondNamedInsured.Text + Environment.NewLine //{10}
            , comboOccupation2.Text + Environment.NewLine //     {11}
            , comboEducation2.Text + Environment.NewLine //      {12}
            , txtBirthDate2.Text + Environment.NewLine //        {13}
            , txtSocial2.Text + Environment.NewLine //           {14}
            , comboGender2.Text + Environment.NewLine //         {15}
            , txtLicense2.Text + Environment.NewLine //          {16}
            , comboMaritalStatus2.Text + Environment.NewLine //  {17}
            , comboRelationToInsured.Text //                     {18}
            , comboYearBuilt.Text + Environment.NewLine //       {19}
            , comboHomeStyle.Text + Environment.NewLine //       {20}
            , txtAcres.Text + Environment.NewLine //             {21}
            , comboUseType.Text + Environment.NewLine //         {22}
            , comboSiding.Text + Environment.NewLine //          {23}
            , comboPrimaryHeat.Text + Environment.NewLine //     {24}
            , comboSecondaryHeat.Text + Environment.NewLine //   {25}
            , txtSquareFeet.Text + Environment.NewLine //        {26}
            , comboBathroom.Text + Environment.NewLine //        {27}
            , comboGarage.Text + Environment.NewLine //          {28}
            , txtGarageSQFT.Text + Environment.NewLine //        {29}
            , comboRoofType.Text + Environment.NewLine //        {30}
            , comboRoofYear.Text + Environment.NewLine //        {31}
            , comboPool.Text + Environment.NewLine //            {32}
            , comboTramp.Text + Environment.NewLine //           {33}
            , comboCarrier.Text + Environment.NewLine //         {34}
            , txtCoverage.Text + Environment.NewLine //          {35}
            , txtAnnualPrem.Text + Environment.NewLine //        {36}
            , txtClaims.Text + Environment.NewLine //            {37}
            , txtPhone.Text + Environment.NewLine //             {38}
            , txtReferral.Text + Environment.NewLine); //        {39}
            File.WriteAllText(saveFileDialog1.FileName, line, Encoding.GetEncoding(1252));
        }
    }
```

// Output creates a file and it all works but when opened in Notepad lines are indented randomly. I am unsure as to why that is?

Output: [Notepad Capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NpLEQ.jpg)

Comment: It is because you have spaces between {0} {1} {2} etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because you have spaces between `{0} {1} {2}` etc. If you remove all the spaces, no lines should be indented.